# SQL Server Like Match and Exclude

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-like

I have a table (DataTable) with a column that contains data like this in one of the columns:

```
DataColumn    
ABCD
ABCE
ABCF
ABXY
```

I have another table (MatchTable) that includes a pattern column and value column that can be used to get matching rows from the DataTable based on the match:

```
MatchPattern   Value
AB%            1
```

I want to exclude the ABCE row from the result set and I don't want to have rows in my match table for ABCD%, ABCF%, etc as the ABCE is the exception to the rule.  My pattern could be AB[^C]%, but that will exclude all ABCs and I only want to exclude ABCE.  The sql for this is:

```
SELECT D.DataColumn, P.Value
FROM MatchTable M
INNER JOIN DataTable D ON D.DataColumn LIKE M.Pattern
```

I know I could add another column to my matching table called something like ExcludePattern with the following:

```
MatchPattern   ExcludePattern Value
AB%            ABCE           1

SELECT D.DataColumn, P.Value
FROM MatchTable M
INNER JOIN DataTable D ON D.DataColumn LIKE M.MatchPattern
                          AND D.DataColumn NOT LIKE M.ExcludePattern
```

I am wondering if there is a way to create a like pattern that will match all ABs except for ABCE in one pattern?  Basically, can this be done using the built-in like or do I have to implement regex?

Comment: Wouldn't `ABC[^E]%` work?

Comment: @l'L'l can you think if that doesn't work if I want anything starting with AB except for CE?  So, AB% except ABCE?  Essentially is there a way to group two letters together as a set like in a regex?

Comment: @l'L'l I updated the question code to include a better encapsulation of my scenario.  I tried to make it a little too specific the first time I think.

Comment: What about `AB_[^E]%`? That would work unless you have a case that is less than 4 characters.

Comment: @DavidFaber I don't think that works as it will exclude ABXE at the same time it excludes ABCE which isn't what I want.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want then with one pattern - not without regex.

Comment: Well, you could use `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`, then it might work in one pattern.

Comment: The OP could do that, if he weren't using SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts guys, i figured as much but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: @David Faber — Ah, very true. It's surprising `SQL` doesn't support  `REGEXP` or `RLIKE` actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's definitely no way to do what you want in a single LIKE pattern.